# Devstack script error

Tags: git, openstack, devstack

I downloaded a script from github for downloading devstack.

The link for the script is: [Devstack script](https://github.com/openstack-dev/devstack/tree/stable/mitaka)

It gives the following error:

```
2016-07-21 05:11:21.594 | Obtaining horizon from git+git://github.com/openstack/horizon.git#egg=horizon (from -r /opt/stack/trove-dashboard/test-requirements.txt (line 5))
2016-07-21 05:11:21.595 |   Cloning git://github.com/openstack/horizon.git to ./src/horizon
2016-07-21 05:11:32.092 | fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
2016-07-21 05:11:32.092 | github.com[0: 192.30.253.112]: errno=Connection refused
2016-07-21 05:11:32.092 | 
2016-07-21 05:11:32.093 | Command "git clone -q git://github.com/openstack/horizon.git /opt/stack/devstack/src/horizon" failed with error code 128 in None
2016-07-21 05:11:32.357 | +inc/python:pip_install:1                  exit_trap
2016-07-21 05:11:32.364 | +./stack.sh:exit_trap:474                  local r=1
2016-07-21 05:11:32.371 | ++./stack.sh:exit_trap:475                  jobs -p
2016-07-21 05:11:32.377 | +./stack.sh:exit_trap:475                  jobs=
2016-07-21 05:11:32.383 | +./stack.sh:exit_trap:478                  [[ -n '' ]]
2016-07-21 05:11:32.389 | +./stack.sh:exit_trap:484                  kill_spinner
2016-07-21 05:11:32.395 | +./stack.sh:kill_spinner:370               '[' '!' -z '' ']'
2016-07-21 05:11:32.400 | +./stack.sh:exit_trap:486                  [[ 1 -ne 0 ]]
2016-07-21 05:11:32.406 | +./stack.sh:exit_trap:487                  echo 'Error on exit'
2016-07-21 05:11:32.406 | Error on exit
2016-07-21 05:11:32.412 | +./stack.sh:exit_trap:488                  generate-subunit 1469077117 775 fail
2016-07-21 05:11:32.716 | +./stack.sh:exit_trap:489                  [[ -z /opt/stack/logs ]]
2016-07-21 05:11:32.722 | +./stack.sh:exit_trap:492                  /opt/stack/devstack/tools/worlddump.py -d /opt/stack/logs
2016-07-21 05:11:33.239 | +./stack.sh:exit_trap:498                  exit 1
```

The simple `git clone -q git://github.com/openstack/horizon.git` is running and downloading over the proxy gateway.
But, its giving error on `git+git://github.com/openstack/horizon.git#egg=horizon`

line No. 5 having this code = `-e git://github.com/openstack/horizon.git#egg=horizon`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

edit this file in trove-deshboard/test-requirements.txt

line No. 5 having this code = 
***-e git+https://github.com/openstack/horizon.git#egg=horizon***